# Print a linked list that is inside a class recursively c++

Tags: c++, list, class, recursion, linked-list

I'm looking for an easiest way to print a private Linked List that is inside a class. (In reverse order)

My method is to call a function of the class that plugs the Head as a parameter and the return is another function that performs the task.

I did this because previously I had to get the Head through a Getter function and then plug it in the function call. All this outside of the class.

```
void Arreglo::InfoDealer(ofstream &salida)
{
    return InfoDealer_f(Head, salida);
}

void Arreglo::InfoDealer_f(NodePTR Ptr, ofstream &salida)
{
    if (Ptr == NULL)
        return;
    InfoDealer_f(Ptr->Next, salida);
    //output stuff
}
```

Is this correct? Is there a better way to do this? Thank You.
I'm new in CS, so please have patience.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your example, but yes, you generally have a public method (the interface) and a private helper method:

```
class my_class
{
    public:
       void print( ostream& out );

    private:
       NodePtr _head;
       void print_helper( NodePtr node, ostream& out );

}

void my_class::print( ostream& out ){ print_helper( _head, out ); }
```

Comment: Thank you! I also learn another thing from your response. I had the helper function public, it should be private it's safer. :)

Comment: actually, the public method should be a free friend-function of the stream-inserter variety.

Comment: @Deduplicator true, there should be a stream insertion operator, but that could just be `return p.print( o );` and have a public member function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you generally have the right idea and your example should work in the end.
Still, some points to consider:

- Use a public friend function of the stream-inserter variety for better idiomatic use:

  ```
  inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const myclass& m) {
      m.print_helper(m._head, o);
      return o;
  }
  // Add in class:
      friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const myclass& m);
  ```
- Don't hide pointers behind a typedef, it just obscures things. `NodePTR` should be `Node*`.

Comment: Maybe `NodePTR` is a `shared_ptr<Node>` in which case it is easier to just typedef it.

Comment: @clcto: That would be over-abstraction in the container and have unjustified overhead.